# d3.js tree layout with array as data structure

Tags: javascript, json, layout, d3.js, tree

I want to create a diagram with d3.js using the tree layout. Instead of the common flare json structure with hierarchical children like:

```
{
    "name":"bla",
    "children":[
      {
         "name":"bla2",
         "someattribute":"green"      
      }
    ]
}
```

I just have an array (of elements which represent a timestep). I always want the next element(s) of the array to be the child(ren) element of the current.
So in fact I want a tree to be generated out of a flattened array. 
My idea was to change the children function of the tree layout like this:

```
    var tree = d3.layout.tree()
    .children(function(d,i) {
        return data[(i+1)];
    })
```

But only one element is displayed in the tree. I don't get it. Shouldn't it iterate over every element when calling `tree.nodes` on `data[0]` ?

To clarify my request: I want to turn an array like `[ele1, ele2, ele3]` into a tree graph that looks like:

```
ele1-->ele2-->ele3
```

Comment: This looks like an abuse of the `.children` function to me -- even if it worked in this particular case, it would be prone to breaking in others. I would strongly recommend formatting your data in a way that makes children more explicit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real issue I see is that the function passed to `.children()` needs to return an Array of children Objects, instead of a single Object as it is now, i.e.

```
var tree = d3.layout.tree()
.children(function(d,i) {
    return i < data.length - 1; data.slice(i+1, i+2) : null;
})
```

It's also important that the leaf node (the last data Object in the array) returns `null` instead of an empty list.

Using this approach, I created a working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mdml/MzG9Y/) that will create a linear tree from an array of objects.

However, I agree with @LarsKotthoff's comment on your post; your code would be better served in terms maintainability and flexibility if you passed `tree.nodes()` a root of an Object in hierarchical format.